# Prolog sudoku error, returns false no matter what

Tags: prolog, sudoku

I have probelm with this:

```
:-use_module(library(clpfd)).

sudoku(R) :- 
            length(R,9), /*red je duzine 9*/
            maplist(same_length(R),R), /*svi redovi su iste duzine*/
            append(R,E), /*elemente svih redova gurnem u jednu listu*/
            E ins 1..9, /* svi elementi te liste su veci od 1 i manji od 9*/
            maplist(all_distinct,R), /*svi elementi po redovimasu medjusobno razliciti*/
            transpose(R,C), /*rotira matricu 90 stepeni u desno i time kolone postaju redovi*/
            maplist(all_distinct, C),
            R = [A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I], /*svaki red dobije ime*/
            kvadratic(A,B,C), /* predkat kvadratic ce se pobrinuti da*/
            kvadratic(D,E,F), /* kvadrati 3 x 3 unutar matrice takodje*/ 
            kvadratic(G,H,I). /* sadrze medjusobno razlicite elemente*/

kvadratic([],[],[]). /* ako smo dosli do praznih lista stane */
kvadratic([E1,E2,E3|T1],[E4,E5,E6|T2],[E7,E8,E9|T3]) :- 
            all_distinct([E1,E2,E3,E4,E5,E6,E7,E8,E9]),
            kvadratic(T1,T2,T3). /* pozovemo za ostatak listi */
```

As you can see this is my code (with some comments, which is same as one on swi prolog website), and when i run it i get just "false". Can someone please help me? Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm... this is the code from [the example on the `transpose/2` page](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=clpfd%3Atranspose/2). It should work, but do you call it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as I expected, problem is something really stupid. In predicate sudoku i used letters C and E for 2 totally different things (they were not the same thing, just 2 separate variables were named by same letter by me). After changing that program works perfectly!